# Flutter - how to get TextField value and display it as a new text

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, flutter

I'm trying to get a value the user types into a TextFormField and then display it as a new message. Now, I can get the value using a controller and display it, the problem is, that I need to display all the messages the user types and stack them on top of each other (just like a messenger).

This is the FormField itself, I understand that I need to save the value the user types and then make a message out of it by sending it somewhere else but I don't know how to do that. (Probably a void that will somehow do that ?)

```
final chatfield = TextFormField(
  controller: myController,
  style: TextStyle(
    decorationColor: Colors.white,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  autofocus: false,
  onSaved: (String value) {
  },
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ),
);
```

The only thing the controller does as of right now is to get the value and display it, I'd like to save and display all the values the user types into the TextFormField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a basic example, you can use `StatefulWidget` , `StreamBuilder` , `FutureBuilder`, etc

```
      class ChatListSample extends StatefulWidget {
        @override
        ChatListSampleState createState() {
          return new ChatListSampleState();
        }
      }

      class ChatListSampleState extends State<ChatListSample> {
        TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();

        List<String> messages = List();

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          final chatfield = TextFormField(
            controller: myController,
            style: TextStyle(
              decorationColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            autofocus: false,
            onSaved: (String value) {},
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          );

          return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
              body: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20, bottom: 100),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: messages.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(messages[index]),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        chatfield,
                        MaterialButton(
                          child: Text("send message"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              messages.add(myController.text);
                              myController.clear();
                            });
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ));
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed !